# VSCode - cannot enter input into console while debugging C++

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I know this was asked many times before, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I am trying to debug a single C++ file on Visual Studio Code on Windows. Running and debugging works fine. However, when I try to debug a program that asks for user input (for example using `cin` or `scanf()`), the process starts and just hangs. The program is waiting for me to input something, however the integrated terminal does not let me type anything in.

One possibility is to run debug in an external terminal, but the problem with the external terminal is that it closes immediately when the program finishes, so I cannot see the result.

Is there an option in launch.json or maybe an extension that would help solve my issue?

Here's my launch.json file:

```
"name": "g++.exe - Générer et déboguer le fichier actif",
"type": "cppdbg",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
"args": [],
"stopAtEntry": false,
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
"environment": [],
"externalConsole": false,
"MIMode": "gdb",
"miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
"setupCommands": [
  {
    "description": "Activer l'impression en mode Pretty pour gdb",
    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
    "ignoreFailures": true
  }
],
"preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
```

Comment: You can always add a break point in the end or add a sleep function to see the results. And there should be an option in VC to launch console that doesn't close immediately after finishing. At least VS has such option.

Comment: Use the debug terminal

Comment: I do not want to fight with the tool by adding breakpoints or sleep in the end every time I debug. I would like there to be a solution that would make it work out of the box, like it works on my VSCode for Linux or Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling MinGW seems to have solved the issue for me. I used the installer from it's [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) page.

I do not know what original the issue was, but now it is possible to type into the terminal when in debug mode. I suspect the issue was with my gdb installation.